# PDE - three restrictions, wave equation (1 dimension)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

I'm not very good at PDEs but this particular problem seems... Strange. It requires that the answer be "continuous (!!)" all in bold.

\begin{align}
u_{tt}&=9u_{xx},\quad x>0,\, t>0,  \\
u(x,t)&=e^{-x}  \\
u_t(x,0)&=\cos(5x)\\  
u_x(0,t)&=u(0,t)+t\\
\end{align}

That last one is giving me trouble, and I'm certain how to interact with it properly... I found a solution to the first 2 restrictions with separation of variables, but I can't see any way to manipulate it to find the third as well.

Could someone point me in the right direction, or barring that, spell out the answer for me?

Comment: $u(x,t) = e^{-x}$? You mean $u(x,0) = e^{-x}$? And the last line is essentially just [Robin boundary conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robin_boundary_condition).

Comment: For this specific example you must consider two different regions. First one is $x<3t$, where the usual d'Alembert's formula applies. In the second region $x>3t$ you must take into account your boundary condition. It seems that the problem requires you to carefully "glue" the two solutions along $x=3t$ such that the resulting solution in all $x>0,t>0$ is continuous.